# PowerShell Get-ChildItem Not always returning a Directory Name

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am searching the drives of multiple servers for a specific file.  The code looks something like this...

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -filter {Name -like "SERVER-*"}
foreach ($server in $Servers){
    $Server.Name
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.Name -ScriptBlock {
        $filename="db2cmd.exe"
        $listOfDrives=(get-psdrive | ? { $_.provider -match 'FileSystem'}).root
        foreach ($Drive in $listOfDrives){
            If ($Drive -ne "C:\" -and $Drive -ne "A:\") {
                Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, in most instances, when the file is encountered, it returns the Directory where the file was found..

```
   Directory: E:\IBM\DB2\SQLLIB\BIN


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                       PSComputerName                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                       --------------                                                                           
-a----         1/5/2024  11:32 AM          55888 db2cmd.exe                                                                                 ServerA
```

Yet on other servers, neither the Directory nor the Column titles are displayed.

```
-a----         1/5/2024  11:32 AM          55888 db2cmd.exe                                                                                 ServerB
```

I really do not understand the reason for this as it is running the same command on each server.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

I have tried different parameters, but they seem to change where and what the Get-ChildItems is looking for, and not the way the results are output.

Comment: There appears to be some code missing - the sample output objects you've shown has a `PSComputerName` property attached, indicating they came from a remoting session.

Comment: Yes, this is comming from a Foreach where I am going through all servers and for each server I perform  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.Name -ScriptBlock {

Comment: Okay, that sounds pretty relevant - can you share the whole loop (or `ForEach-Object` pipeline if that's what you're using)?

Comment: I added the full Code "please note I changed the -Like "Server-*" from its actual value for security reasons.  In the original, I also changed the PSComputerName to a ficticious value, again for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated your original post with the code you posted below. The script outputs `$Server.Name`, but that's not shown in your output - do you just get empty lines in between the servers?

Comment: The formatted output is likely broken up by the interjection of `$Server.Name` - `powershell.exe` generally "remembers" the formatting choices it made for the last output item, so that what's rendered on screen looks more smooth. Try removing it completely and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is normally used as a functional language and as such should only return one object.

As @Mathias R. Jessen, states. You are trying to `return` both `$Server.Name` and the result of `Get-ChildItem` and PowerShell really don't care about the order returned, so they might interact and mix up in the output.

You might get other results if you actually specify it should be pure outputs using `Write-Output` instead.

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "SERVER-*"}

foreach ($Server in $Servers){
  Write-Output $Server.Name
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name {
    $FileName = 'db2cmd.exe'
    $ListOfDrives = (Get-PsDrive | where Provider -match 'FileSystem').Root

    foreach ($Drive in $ListOfDrives){
      if ($Drive -ne 'C:\' -and $Drive -ne 'A:\') {
        $Db2CmdFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -Filter $FileName -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
        Write-Output $Db2CmdFiles
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the best option would be adding the `$Server.Name` property to the object returned by `Get-ChildItem`. Then there could be no object mix up.
(On the other hand, that property is already available in PsComputerName since you are using remote sessions.)

Comment: I tried this, and it is still giving the same exact results.  It is always on the same servers, it will not show the "Directory" where the file is being found.  Unfortunately, that is exactly the information I am trying to return.

Comment: Is that server using the same version of PowerShell?